# How to find the splitting field of $X^4-10X^2+1$?

Tags: field-theory, splitting-field

How to find the splitting field of $X^4-10X^2+1$ ? 
I found the roots

\begin{align*}
X^4-10X^2+1=0&\iff (X^2-5)^2-24=0\\
&\iff X^2-5=\pm 2\sqrt 6\\
&\iff X^2=5\pm 2\sqrt 6\\
&\iff X\in\left\{\sqrt{5+2\sqrt 6},\sqrt{5-2\sqrt 6},-\sqrt{5+2\sqrt 6},-\sqrt{5-2\sqrt 6}\right\}
\end{align*}

But I'm not able to continue...

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{6}}=\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}$

Comment: The splitting field of a polynomial over a field (in this case I assume $\mathbb{Q}$) is the smallest field extension in which it splits. If $f(X) \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ has roots $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ then the splitting field is simply $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$. Do you have any other requirements for what the splitting field should look like?

Comment: Your only splitting field (up to isomorphism) is $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4)$ where you have calculated $\alpha_i$s. But you want to simplify it, right ?

Comment: yes it's what I want.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $(\sqrt 3 + \sqrt 2)^2 = 5 + 2\sqrt6$ and $(\sqrt 3 - \sqrt 2)^2 = 5 - 2\sqrt 6$, so your splitting field contains $\sqrt 2$ and $\sqrt 3$.

Comment: so it's $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3)$ ?